# Can we access A360 or other forge Hubs using Azure credentials

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to link the Azure identity management with A360 and other hubs of Autodesk?
It is pain to map the A360 accounts with Azure accounts. If Azure single sign on can be used, it will simplify things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Autodesk ID is the only supported SSO provider for the Forge Platform.
Sorry for the bad news.